# WPF Controls Visibility

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm new in WPF and I Want to hide/show some controls like TextBlock, ComboBox etc from code behind depending of a ComboBox Value. I've searched for some solutions without luck. I often the follow answer.

textbox1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

So, I tried this one.

```
    private void cbBuscar_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(cbBuscar.SelectedIndex.ToString());

        if (cbBuscar.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
           cbProduto.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        }
        else if (cbBuscar.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            cbProduto.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else if (cbBuscar.SelectedIndex == 2)
        {
            cbProduto.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
```

It simple does not work. Trying that I get this error {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

Do what I'm trying must not be hard, actually it must be pretty easy. Then, could anyone tell what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is Exception Coming on Selecting Item in ComboBox or Sumwhere else?

Comment: Your cbProduto might be null.

Comment: try running it in the debugger and seeing if cbBuscar or cbProduto is null.

Comment: Yes, you both are right the cbProduto is null. However I also have a TextBlock named lblProduto and it's null as well. How can a TextBlock being null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try placing the following code inside your `cbBuscar_SelectionChanged` function:

```
if (!IsLoaded)
    return;
```

If the selection is changing before the window initializes, this may fix the problem.

So your function would look like this:

```
private void cbBuscar_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsLoaded)
        return;

    MessageBox.Show(cbBuscar.SelectedIndex.ToString());

    if (cbBuscar.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
       cbProduto.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    }
    else if (cbBuscar.SelectedIndex == 1)
    {
        cbProduto.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
    else if (cbBuscar.SelectedIndex == 2)
    {
        cbProduto.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ming, you got the point!
Could you please tell me why does it happen, Using this way my code doesn't run in the load of the page, why should I do? I could set some controls as Hidden by default but must be another way to verify that on OnLoad, any suggestion?

Comment: You need to call the function after the `InitializeComponent()` call in the window constructor. The problem is that, during initialization, some of the controls have not yet been created. This causes problems, as in your case, if some controls raise events which reference other controls which have not been initialized, hence the NullReferenceException.